# Find the line $t$ that is concurrent to $r$ and $s$ and parallel to $MN$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to find the vector equation for the line $t$ that is concurrent to both:

$$r:X = (1,1,-1)+\lambda(2,1,-1)$$
and $$s:\\x+y-3z = 1\\2x-y-2z=0$$

And also, $t$ is parallel to $MN$ when:
$$M = (1,-1,4), N = (0,3,-1)\implies\vec {MN} = (-1,-2,-5)$$

I tried to write a generic point for $r$:

$$P = (1+2\lambda, 1+\lambda, -1-\lambda)$$
And in $s$ when we let $x = \lambda$ we get the generic point:

$$Q = (\lambda, 1+\frac{4}{5}\lambda, \frac{3}{5}\lambda)$$

I tried to calculate $$\vec {PQ} = (-1+t-2\lambda, \frac{4}{5}t-\lambda, 1+\frac{3t}{5} + \lambda)$$

And then make $$\vec {PQ} = a\vec{MN}$$ for some alpha. When I did this, I [got no solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2Bt-2%20%CE%BB%20%3D%20-a%3B%20%284%20t%29%2F5-%CE%BB%20%3D%20-2a%3B%20%201%2B%283%20t%29%2F5%2B%CE%BB%20%3D%20-5a). Please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking $P=(1+2\lambda,1+\lambda,-1-\lambda)$ as above,

we can represent the general point on s by $Q=(2+5t,2+4t,1+3t)$.

Then $\vec{PQ}=\langle1+5t-2\lambda,1+4t-\lambda,2+3t+\lambda\rangle$, so

setting $\vec{PQ}=k(\vec{MN})=k\langle -1,4,-5\rangle$ gives the system of equations

$\;\;\;5t-2\lambda+k=-1$, $\;\;\;4t-\lambda-4k=-1$, $\;\;\;3t+\lambda+5k=-2$.

Now solve for $t$ and $\lambda$ to find the points $P$ and $Q$, and then you can write a vector equation for the line.

Comment: How did you find $Q$? I used $x=\lambda$ but I got a different point.

Comment: I took the cross-product of the normal vectors to get a direction vector for the line, and then I found a point on the line.

Comment: But is my point wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think you wanted to have $Q=(\lambda,\frac{4}{5}\lambda+\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5}\lambda-\frac{1}{5})$